# ¿Cómo puedo bloquear el envío de formularios a un usuario por un tiempo en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, datetime

Estoy realizando una web donde la gente se registra con su correo y una contraseña, luego hace posts con fotos y más datos. Los posts automáticamente se van a la página de inicio. Es detalle está en que no quisiera que un usuario suba 20 posts en un día para que solo pueda verse el de él. Entonces quiero que ese usuario no pueda volver a publicar un post(mediante un formulario) por 3 días. Estaba pensando en que cuando el usuario haga un post exitoso, cambie su "status" de 1 a 0, después de 3 días vuelva a 1, ya que hice una condición para que ese formulario pueda ser redirigido solo si su estado es "1".

No les dejo el código por que no sé ni qué ponerles, pero me gustaría que me den algunas salidas quizás más óptimas por favor.

Comment: Vas bien, pero debes intentar algo, lo que sea. Aunque sea un formulario simplificado, la tabla en la que llevarás el control con ese campo de estado, ... Pero todo al mínimo

Comment: Puedes crear un campo, en la tabla de usuarios, que indique la fecha de la ultima publicacion y con ese puedes realizar la validacion.